# Is this easy like 2+2?

Tags: riddle

Just another riddle.

Clue 1:

> Like touched on the title, it's used to make some operations

Clue 2:

> You're using one of them at the moment

Clue 3:

> You can tell it what to do

Clue 4:

> 10 letters

**Who am I?**

Comment: Clue 1 seems to describe a _singular_ thing. Clue 2 seems to describe a _plural_ thing. Clue 3 seems to describe a _plural_ thing. Clue 4 could be either. The final question seems to want a _singular_ thing. Is this inconsistency deliberate? If not, would you like to clarify whether we're looking for a singular or a plural answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> CALCULATOR
>
>  It makes operations, all computers with web browsing capabilities have calculators, you tell it what to compute.

Other possibilities:

> Technology, electronic, Cell phones, appliances

Comment: I see you're a man of culture as well, the answer was `Calculator` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **COMPUTERS**.

They can do arithmetic and other logical operations.

You are using a computer (cell phones count if you're on mobile).

You can program them.

The word is 9 letters long.

If a computer is part of an AI, they could be referred to as a "who". *(singular and plural seems to be weird in general, but AI using plural "I" to refer to the hive mind as a whole can make sense.)*

Comment: Good attempt, it has a logic, but I'm sorry to say that I accidentally wrote 9 letters instead of 10. Anyway, I think you can do it the same